# How to immediately update CSS on state change

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

In React Native, I have this component:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.selectItem}>
  <Text
       style={this.getTextIndexStyle()}>
      {someText}
  </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This `Text` component calls this method to get its styling:

```
getTextIndexStyle() {
    return {
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: 0.75,
        backgroundColor: this.getTextBoxColor(),
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    };
}
```

Which in turn calls this method to get its color.

```
getTextBoxColor() {
    if(this.state.highlighted) {
        return Constants.HIGHLIGHTED_TEXT_BOX_COLOR;
    }
    return Constants.UNHIGHLIGHTED_TEXT_BOX_COLOR;
}
```

Also, when the user clicks the `TouchableHighlight`, he or she triggers this:

```
selectItem() {
    this.setState({highlighted: true});
}
```

My problem is that if I click on the `TouchableHighlight`, the `Text` component doesn't change its colour.

I'm not sure if `this.state` is not updated or if it is updated but for some strange reason `this.getTextBoxColor()` is not called.

Any idea how to make the colour update?

Comment: you could log inside render value of state and check if it got updated or not (or if it will get called actually after selectItem-if not state wasn't changed)

Comment: Add a key of the state property highlighted, so when it changes it tells React to update the dom.

Comment: I changed `selectItem()` to `selectItem = () => {}` and now the state is updated, but only after a few clicks. Ay idea why it's so slow and how to make it faster?

Comment: You might have to manually trigger a re-render.

Comment: @ChrisG how do I do that?

Comment: @octavian Sorry, never mind. According to the docs, every state change should trigger a re-render, so it looks like you can only prevent one, not force one.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the JSX of the onPress of your TouchableHighlight, you can fix it by changing to:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.selectItem}>
```

You should also create a StyleSheet and pass the color you wish to it during rendering

```
const style = (backgroundColor) => (
    StyleSheet.create({
        textStyle: {
            position: 'absolute',
            opacity: 0.75,
            backgroundColor,
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#ffffff',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold'
     })
);
```

then, on you render method:

```
render(){
     const styles=style(getTextBoxColor())
     return(
          ...
     )
}
```

and on your Text:

```
  <Text
       style={styles.textStyle}>
      {someText}
  </Text>
```

EDIT: ({backgroundColor}) => (backgroundColor)